# How to convert multiple columns i.e time ,year,month and date into datetime format in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Data frame has 4 columns year,month,date,hhmm

hhmm - is hour and minute concatenated 
eg: 10:30 is equal to 1030

```
dd=spark.createDataFrame([(2019,2,13,1030),(2018,2,14,1000),(2029,12,13,0300)],["Year","month","date","hhmm"])
dd.collect()
```

expected output in datetime format in pyspark dataframe dd

```
dd.collect()
2019-02-13 10:30:00 
2018-2-14 10:00:00  
2019-12-13 03:00:00
```

Comment: you could concatenate with `concat()` and then convert to `timestamp` using `from_unixtime()` with `unix_timestamp()`

Comment: df.select(concat(col("Year"), lit("-"), col("month"),lit("-"), col("date"),lit(" "), col("hhmm")))    still im getting error and how to convert 1030 to 10:30:00

Comment: are your columns in string? importing your hhmm with 0300 as `int` will not return 0300. it returns `192`

Comment: once you handle the single digit dates/months to two digits, and your hhmm as four digits. you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('concatedcol'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HHmm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`. I am using the format from your mentioned code above.

Comment: incase you are getting the data from a database source. then I think you will only have to take care of the one digit to two digit dates and months

Comment: actually im importing csv file as dataframe and all values are integer type

Comment: yep, that should work fine. just take care of the date, month, hhmm columns by converting it to string, and add leading zero (string)

Comment: I'm from R background new to pyspark .In R has function called mktime(year = 1970, month = 10, day = 10, hour = 02, minute =30,  second = 0, msec = 0) which results in 1970/10/10 02:30:00 .Is there any similar function in pyspark

Comment: ah! that makes sense now. i think it can be done easily in python using `mktime()`. However in pyspark there is no function that does the same thing. [function module](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) and [example](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/timestamp-conversion.html)

Comment: Thank you samkart i got output as i expected for this code
```dt=dd.select(concat(col("Year"), lit("-"), col("month"),lit("-"),col("date"), lit(" "),floor(col("hhmm")/100), lit(":"),col("hhmm")%100,lit(":"),lit("00")).alias('datetime1'))                                                                                                              
                                                           
                                  dt.select(to_timestamp(dt.datetime1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').alias('datetime1')).collect()```

Comment: obtain datetime1 is local time i need to just append timezone to it so that i can convert it later into UTC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193182/discussion-between-premon-and-samkart).

Answer (score 3):

For Spark 3+, you can use [`make_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_timestamp) function :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dd = dd.withColumn(
    "time",
    F.expr("make_timestamp(Year, month, date, substr(hhmm,1,2), substr(hhmm,3,2), 0)")
)

dd.show(truncate=False)

#+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
#|Year|month|date|hhmm|time               |
#+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
#|2019|2    |13  |1030|2019-02-13 10:30:00|
#|2018|2    |14  |1000|2018-02-14 10:00:00|
#|2029|12   |13  |0300|2029-12-13 03:00:00|
#+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your data, 0300 integer will not load as the desired format, for me it loaded as 192, so first you have to load it as string, you just need to assign the data types using schema when doing the load. Refer to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv). E.g. for a .csv:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("Year", StringType(), True), StructField("month", StringType(), True), StructField("date", StringType(), True), StructField("hhmm", StringType(), True)])

dd = DataFrameReader.csv(path='your/data/path', schema=schema)
```

After that you need to fix the data format and convert it to timestamp:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dd = spark.createDataFrame([('2019','2','13','1030'),('2018','2','14','1000'),('2029','12','13','300')],["Year","month","date","hhmm"])

dd = (dd.withColumn('month', F.when(F.length(F.col('month')) == 1, F.concat(F.lit('0'), F.col('month'))).otherwise(F.col('month')))
        .withColumn('date', F.when(F.length(F.col('date')) == 1, F.concat(F.lit('0'), F.col('date'))).otherwise(F.col('date')))
        .withColumn('hhmm', F.when(F.length(F.col('hhmm')) == 1, F.concat(F.lit('000'), F.col('hhmm')))
                             .when(F.length(F.col('hhmm')) == 2, F.concat(F.lit('00'), F.col('hhmm')))
                             .when(F.length(F.col('hhmm')) == 3, F.concat(F.lit('0'), F.col('hhmm')))
                             .otherwise(F.col('hhmm')))
        .withColumn('time', F.to_timestamp(F.concat(*dd.columns), format='yyyyMMddHHmm'))
     )

dd.show()

+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
|Year|month|date|hhmm|               time|
+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
|2019|   02|  13|1030|2019-02-13 10:30:00|
|2018|   02|  14|1000|2018-02-14 10:00:00|
|2029|   12|  13|0300|2029-12-13 03:00:00|
+----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Great answer. How do we convert year into last 2 digits only ?

Comment: @Kenny You can cast it to string and then use the substring function.